# Errors in boto connection to Mturk

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto, mechanicalturk

I'm working on boto versioned 2.6.0 . I have a problem with connecting to mturk.
My code is :

```
mturk_connection = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, is_secure = True, host = HOST)
print mturk_connection.get_account_balance()
```

The error message i get is :

```
boto.mturk.connection.MTurkRequestError: MTurkRequestError: 200 OK  
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <GetAccountBalanceResponse>

            <OperationRequest>
            <RequestId>06783745-3810-49d3-8235-d8a95f36b747</RequestId>
            <Errors>
                <Error>
                    <Code>AWS.BadClaimsSupplied</Code>
                    <Message>The specified claims are invalid.   Based on your request, your signature should be generated using the following string: ActionGetAccountBalanceAWSAccessKeyIdAKIAQEQC5M72KQQSignatureVersion1Timestamp2012-11-15T06:10:07ZVersion2012-03-25.  Check to make sure your system clock and timezone is not incorrect.  Our current system time: 2012-11-15T06:10:07Z.  (1352959808079 s)</Message>        
                    <Data>
                            <Key>CustomerSignature</Key>
                            <Value>eMfIjDkM7v2/4fp4WqTOjtaFGDp1/Ydr2TTVV+oP5m0=</Value>
                            </Data><Data>
                            <Key>StringToSign</Key>
                                <Value>ActionGetAccountBalanceAWSAccessKeyIdAKIAJD3HEQEQC5M72KQQSignatureVersion1Timestamp2012-11-15T06:10:07ZVersion2012-03-25</Value>
                            </Data><Data>
                            <Key>SystemTime</Key>
                            <Value>2012-11-15T06:10:07Z</Value>
                    </Data>
            </Error>
        </Errors>
    </OperationRequest>

</GetAccountBalanceResponse>
```

I tried finding out the source of the error but failed. Please suggest something.

Comment: I saw you reviewed in the suggested edits section, which requires 2k rep, you have 25, therefore U R HAXR!

Comment: thanks for the update.. **Find an answer if u can**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have the older version of boto where bug fix #1057 hasn't been updated.please check line number 525 for an **'init'** method.If you don't find one .. re-clone the boto repository from [github](https://github.com/boto/boto)  again  and install using the command -

```
python setup.py install
```

Hope your problem gets solved.